# Eigen: Can't use norm() for Vector2i

Tags: eigen

I can't do:

```
Vector2i vec(0, 1, 2);
cout << vec.norm() << endl;
```

as it gives a compiler error which mentions: `THIS_FUNCTION_IS_NOT_FOR_INTEGER_NUMERIC_TYPES` in some failing assertion.

I could do:

```
Vector2i i_vec(0, 1, 2);
Vector2f f_vec;
f_vec = i_vec.cast<float>();
cout << f_vec.norm() << endl;
```

which works obviously.

Question: Any reason why the `norm` method isn't defined for `VectorXi`?

Maybe Eigen uses the element type of the `Vector` to determine the return type for `norm()` (in which case it makes sense that `norm()` wouldn't be defined for a return type of `int`)?

Just curious.

Comment: I don't think there is a mathematical sence in Euclidean norm on integer vector space. You can't normalize integer vectors.

Comment: The same problem comes to me when I try to get the inverse of row elementary matrix. I fixed it by using ```cast()``` function mentioned by @ggael below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I remember the action of a `norm()` function correctly, it takes a square root of some input. Square root, obviously, is non-integer in many cases. On the other hand, if I remember logic of eigen package, once you have declared a matrix of particular elements (`int, double, complex<double>`), it works with elements of this type only. So you were absolutely right with your suggestion.

Comment: to complete the answer, let me add that you do not need to create a temporary: `i_vec.cast<float>().norm()`, and you can also compute the squared norm: `i_vec.squaredNorm()` and take the square root afterward if needed.

Comment: Didn't think of `squaredNorm()`. Thanks.